# Is this ArrayAdapter suitable for use with CommonsWare MergeAdapter? If so, why is it not working?

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-adapter, listadapter, commonsware-cwac

I'm attempting to use CommonsWare's `MergeAdapter` class and having limited success. In particular, I am not sure if 1) my `ArrayAdapter` is suitable for use, 2) if I am adding it correctly, and 3) if I am doing all that is necessary to wire everything up.

Here is my subclass of `ArrayAdapter`:

```
class PDLAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<PartnerDisease> {

    public PDLAdapter(final Context context) {
        super(context, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.partnerdisease_list_item, null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.populateViews(getItem(position));

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Here is my object `StructuredSubDisease` (the name makes no sense if you actually consider it's a top-level object containing sub diseases, but whatever):

```
class StructuredSubDisease {
    public String headingText;
    public ArrayList<PartnerDisease> subDiseases;

    public View headingView() {
        View returnView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.partnerdisease_list_item, null);
        TextView t = (TextView) returnView.findViewById(R.id.tv_displayname);
        t.setText(headingText);
        return returnView;
    }
}
```

...and here is where the "magic" is supposed to be happening.

```
            for (StructuredSubDisease s : subDiseaseList) {
                mMergeAdapter.addView(s.headingView()); // @Alex, <--- thing 1

                PartnerDiseaseListAdapter adapter = new PartnerDiseaseListAdapter(this);

                for (PartnerDisease p : s.subDiseases) {
                    adapter.add(p);
                }

                mMergeAdapter.addAdapter(adapter); // <--- and thing 2
            }
```

I have `Log`ged the count:

```
   Log.i("mergecount", "" + mMergeAdapter.getCount());
```

This returns `1`, where I would expect `2`.

EDIT: I forgot to mention, the result of this is that the `headingView()` is displayed with the proper heading text, but there is no list beneath it.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: @Alex, because I added two things - the `headingView()` (which is rendered) and the `adapter` (which silently fails).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> my ArrayAdapter is suitable for use

It seems OK.

> if I am adding it correctly

It seems OK.

> if I am doing all that is necessary to wire everything up

You don't have any diseases, apparently.

> because I added two things - the headingView() (which is rendered) and the adapter (which silently fails)

`getCount()` returns the number of total rows that should be in your `ListView`, not the number of things added to the `MergeAdapter`. In your case, it would appear that you have no diseases.

Start by putting your `PartnerDiseaseListAdapter` directly into your `ListView`, ignoring the `MergeAdapter`. Get that working. Then, switch back to the `MergeAdapter`.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. The issue was the list. Silly of me not to check. Is there a method available for getting the number of views+adapters added to your `MergeAdapter` or is that something that would generally not be useful?

Comment: @jshin47: I don't have a method for getting the account of added pieces, as I haven't seen or heard of a need. If you have a concrete scenario for it, file an issue on the project. It's trivial to add, but I like keeping a lean API.